# Accessing Properties from Classes inside of traits

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, traits, mockery

I'm trying to write a unit test for the `startedAt()` method using mocks however the problem I'm facing is that I don't think I can access the builder instance from inside that `startedAt()` method.

To test the `startedAt()` method I created a fixture class called `ExampleFilters` and had it extend the parent class of `Filters`. Inside of the `ExampleFilters` class I import the `FiltersByStartDate` trait.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can access the `builder` property from the `FiltersByStartDate` trait?

Any ideas on this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters\Concerns;

trait FiltersByStartDate
{
    /**
     * Filter a query to include models of a specific date started.
     *
     * @param  array  $startedAt
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function startedAt($startedAt)
    {
        if (isset($startedAt[1])) {
            $this->builder->whereHas('currentEmployment', function ($query) use ($startedAt) {
                $query->whereBetween('started_at', [
                    $startedAt[0],
                    $startedAt[1]
                ]);
            });
        } else {
            $this->builder->whereHas('currentEmployment', function ($query) use ($startedAt) {
                $query->whereDate('started_at', $startedAt[0]);
            });
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Fixtures;

use App\Filters\Concerns\FiltersByStartDate;
use App\Filters\Filters;

class ExampleFilters extends Filters
{
    use FiltersByStartDate;
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class Filters
{
    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * The Eloquent builder.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected $builder;

    /**
     * Registered filters to operate upon
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $filters = [];

    /**
     * Create a new class instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the filters.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function apply($builder)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;

        foreach ($this->getFilters() as $filter => $value) {
            if (method_exists($this, $filter)) {
                $this->$filter($value);
            }
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all relevant filters from the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array_filter($this->request->only($this->filters));
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Filters\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Tests\Fixtures\ExampleFilters;
use Tests\TestCase;

/*
 * @group filters
 */
class FiltersByStartDateTest extends TestCase
{
    /* @var Tests\Fixtures\ExampleFilters */
    protected $subject;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->subject = app(ExampleFilters::class);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function models_can_be_filtered_by_their_start_date()
    {
        // $this->markTestIncomplete();

        $dateSet = ['2020-01-01 00:00:00'];

        $mock = \Mockery::mock(Builder::class)
            ->shouldReceive('whereHas', \Mockery::any())
            ->shouldReceive('whereDate')
            ->withArgs(['started_at', $dateSet])
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true)
            ->getMock();

        dd($this->subject->startedAt($dateSet));

        $builderMockFromDate = $this->subject->startedAt($dateSet);

        $this->assertSame($builderMockFromDate, $mock);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like you're using traits incorrectly. `A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.` Generally speaking, the trait shouldnt use properties that only exist in the classes that use the trait. If the trait needs a property to work, then that property should be a property of the trait, not the class using the trait. Creating a trait that relies on a property of the using class adds complexity and dependency on that class or extending classes

Comment: The reason for the trait is that I have 6 XXXFilters classes that all use the same startedAt method so I thought to make a trait and include it.

Comment: `how I can access the builder property from the FiltersByStartDate trait?`, you cant. FiltersByStartDate doesnt have a `builder` property.  You can access the "builder" property of `ExampleFilters` though.  `(new ExampleFilters($request))->builder`

Comment: In there lies the problem. I can't hardcode ExampleFilters because if this trait is used by 6 different classes then that's a problem.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the test you're trying to write that requires you to `access the builder property from the FiltersByStartDate trait`, perhaps there's a different way to do this that doesnt actually require that. Or again, you could add the `builder` property to the trait itself, then you're free to mock that property/getter in your tests to setup whatever you need

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I've included the test above. I'm also starting to wonder if I should create a parent class called EmployableFilters which the ExampleFilters would extend from and would extend the `FIlters` class. But I don't know the best way to go.

Comment: @WesleySmith does that help you above?